# Does the paper "On the cobordism ring $\Omega_*$ and a complex analogue II" exist?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism

I've been investigating the Milnor hypersurfaces, and every reference seems to point to the paper by Milnor, "On the cobordism ring $\Omega_*$ and a complex analogue II". Despite my best efforts, I cannot seem to find it. Was this paper ever published? If not, is there a draft that is available?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's what John Milnor writes about this, in his collected works:

> The projected Part II of this paper
>   was never written. In fact I am
>   chagrined to discover that I have
>   never published any details about some
>   of the announced results which were
>   intended to appear in it. I was very grateful when Thom gave me permission to reprint his 1959 Bourbaki lecture, "*Travaux de Milnor sur le cobordism*", which gives a better account of this work than anything which I have published.

(page 249 of Part III of the Collected Papers of John Milnor, AMS 2007).

The paper by René Thom which Milnor mentions can be accessed [here](https://eudml.org/doc/109572).